# Can't access my Ubuntu admin account

Tags: users, data-recovery, password-recovery

It just shows a black screen with words in it for a fraction of a second and then gets back to users screen(where you choose your user).
I tried to enter from another account and removed the password for the admin account , but it didn't work too , and then I couldn't access my admin privileged places with my old password ?

What should I do ?

I tried to change my password from recovery but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me also (in Ubuntu 12.04)
I did the following. 
Hope its of some help.

- Enter the log in screen
- Press CTRL+ALT+F1, (to revert back press CTRL+ALT+F7, though it won't be needed)
- login with your username/password
- ls -Shla | grep "Xauthority"
- sudo mv .Xauthority Xauthority.old
- sudo shutdown -r now